# Symmetric circulant matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to create symmetric circulant matrices.

Example of order 4:

```
1 2 : 3 4
2 1 : 4 3
.........
3 4 : 1 2
4 3 : 2 1
```

Example of order 8:

```
1 2 3 4 : 5 6 7 8
2 1 4 3 : 6 5 8 7
3 4 1 2 : 7 8 5 6
4 3 2 1 : 8 7 6 5
..................
5 6 7 8 : 1 2 3 4
6 5 8 7 : 2 1 4 3
7 8 5 6 : 3 4 1 2
8 7 6 5 : 4 3 2 1
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: What's the definition you are using here? Would the input just be the number 4?

Comment: Yes, all the inputs are numbers. This is just a one example.

Comment: Here's a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795318/efficient-way-to-create-a-circulant-matrix-in-r

Comment: But I need first row and first column in this order.

Comment: But your example doesn't match the definition of "circulant" on wikipedia. So what definition are you using?

Comment: My bad. It's kind of circulant. I just added order 8 example. What if I want to do order 12, 16, and so on?

Comment: Well, you haven't provided the definition that you are using for this matrix. I have no idea what the order would look like for 12 or 16. What is the rule you are using to generate your desired matrix? It just looks like a mess of numbers.

Comment: I just edited my matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to solve the problem but is way too clever. The `flip(x)==1` idiom gives a matrix (once converted to numeric) of the form `[0 1; 1 0]` ...

```
flip <- function(x) x[rev(seq(nrow(x))),]
x <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1),2)
x2 <- kronecker(2*(flip(x)==1),x,"+")   ## 4x4 solution
x3 <- kronecker(4*(flip(x)==1),x2,"+")  ## 8x8 solution
```

Repeat for larger matrices of size `2^n` (embed in a `for` loop if you want to do this a lot) ...  I don't know what your desired answer would be for a matrix that's not of size `2^n` (e.g. 12x12), but you might be able to find a way to extend this machinery.