# R function for manipulative field experiment design - Plant ecology

Tags: r, random, experimental-design

I am a plant ecologist and I would like to design a field manipulative experiment. To achieve a good degree of randomisation in the disposition of plants inside experimental plots, I would like to use R (with which I'm familiar).

The picture is a schematisation of the design: in total there would be 6 plots, each containing 24 different plant species. In total I have 36 plant species, from which I would like to randomly sample 24 species per plot (with high variation between plots). Each species should be present in 4 out of the 6 plots but in different positions, twice along the border (in two of the warm colours) and twice in the core area (once per cold colour); in the picture I visually explain what I mean using 4 different species (A, B, C, D).

Could anyone suggest a way to do it or some insight to write the function?

[image: Plot design]

Comment: Took me a long time to figure out how to randomize the groups, but it was fun and mind bending.

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed some insight from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242944/how-to-generate-random-matrix-without-repetition-in-rows-and-cols) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795318/efficient-way-to-create-a-circulant-matrix-in-r). Basically, you make a circular matrix and shuffle groups.

```
coords <- list(c(1,1),c(1,2),c(2,1),c(3,1),
c(1,3),c(1,4),c(2,4),c(3,4),
c(2,2),c(3,2),c(2,3),c(3,3),
c(4,1),c(5,1),c(6,1),c(6,2),
c(4,2),c(5,2),c(4,3),c(5,3),
c(4,4),c(5,4),c(6,3),c(6,4))

Matrix <- matrix(c(LETTERS,0:9)[1:36][matrix(1:36,36+1,36+1,byrow=T)[c(1,36:2),1:36]],36,36)
PlotLayouts <- Matrix[(1:6*6),1:24][,unlist(lapply(split(1:24,rep(1:6,each=4)),sample,4))]
PlotLayouts <- split(PlotLayouts,sample(1:6,6))

Result <- lapply(PlotLayouts,function(Vector){
  Layout <- matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=4)
  for(i in 1:24){
    Layout[coords[[i]][1],coords[[i]][2]] <- Vector[i]
  }
  Layout
})

#Species Counts
table(unlist(Result))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 

Result
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "I"  "H"  "M"  "L" 
[2,] "K"  "R"  "S"  "N" 
[3,] "J"  "P"  "Q"  "O" 
[4,] "U"  "Z"  "0"  "2" 
[5,] "V"  "Y"  "X"  "1" 
[6,] "T"  "W"  "4"  "3" 

$`2`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "0"  "Z"  "4"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "9"  "A"  "5" 
[3,] "1"  "7"  "8"  "6" 
[4,] "C"  "H"  "I"  "K" 
[5,] "D"  "G"  "F"  "J" 
[6,] "B"  "E"  "M"  "L" 
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ian!! The result of this code is very similar to what I'm looking for, but in all of the matrixes it's the same 24 letters repeating, and not a subsample of 36 letters (longer than the latin alphabeth ahah). Also, would there be a way to avoid the letters from repeating in all 6 matrixes, but just in 4 of them? It's very complicated, I know...

Comment: OK, here is with 36 species. It's not random, but I think it will do for your purposes.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :) One last thing, only if you have time/feel like still helping me, do you think there's a way to make sure that each character appears twice on the edge of the matrix and twice in the inner area ((2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),(4,2),(4,3),(5,2),(5,3)? Right now it appears three times in the edge and once in the inner area. I'm super grateful for the help!